# How to get json data out of if statement?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the data variable out of if-else statement in the global scope how can I do it?

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'API Url');
request.send();

request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
    if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);   // Data Variable
}
});

console.log(data); //gives error
```

Comment: Even if you fix the scope problem your code will not work. The request is *asynchronous*, so `data` will not be set until the request response is received.

Comment: this is asynchronous code , so fixing scope wont work. you will need to put your code inside callback function

Answer (score 0):

Move out data variable from scope.

```
let data = {}; 
request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
    if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){
    data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);   // Data Variable
}
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: This is the answer. However, it's better practice to use `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: It still won't work.

Comment: @Pointy Correct! Do you know the solution

Comment: @ronitgupta see the linked duplicate. It's an asynchronous operation, so the value will not be available until the final state change event fires. You *can't* get the value outside of that without using a Promise mechanism or `async/await` (which is based on Promises).

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the data variable outside the function block to get it globally, currently, it is inside a functional scope

More on scopes [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/#:%7E:text=JavaScript%20has%20two%20scopes%20%E2%80%93%20global,function%20and%20any%20nested%20functions.)

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'API Url');
request.send();

var data = {}; // Declare here

request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
    if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){
        data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);   // Data Variable
    }
});

console.log(data); //gives error
```

Comment: Didn't work ! It just logs out the empty object. JSON Data still is inside the function

Answer (score 0):

Please put `data` out

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'API Url');
request.send();

let data = 'Data Variable';
request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
    if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){
    data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);   // Data Variable
}
});

console.log(data);
```